# Tailwind justify content property missing when build for React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I build a React project with `create build` based on the Tailwind docs.
It works fine when in dev mode but the problem is the build version missing `justify-end` property although another justify-content still working. When I inspect it, the Chrome DevTools doesn't have any information about the `justify-end` class.

[image]